# Change order of Google Map controls in the same location (i.e. RIGHT_TOP)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to rearrange the default controls in the Google Map (v3, 3.4) API.

Everything is in place and works, but when I add the *mapTypeControl*, *zoomControl*, the *streetViewControl* and the *panControl* to the same *ControlPosition* (i.e. google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP), I can't define the order of how they are rendered.

*mapTypeControl* has a default of TOP_RIGHT, but changing it to RIGHT_TOP (the default of the other ones mentioned above) add's it to the bottom in this location:

[image: google maps controls]

Here's the code for the map options (nevermind the added OSM layer):

```
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 12,
center: def_center, // is set before this snippet    
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeId: user_maptype, // is set before this snippet
mapTypeControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP,
    mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, "openstreetmap"]
},
zoomControl: true,
zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
},
streetViewControl: true,
streetViewControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
},
panControl: false,
panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
},
scaleControl: false,
scaleControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT
}
};
```

I need the *mapTypeControl* to be the first element to be rendered (above the streetViewControl). Any idea how to do this?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to reordering this? i added a custom control and can put it above or below with index 1/0, but I can't update the index of the default controls (specifically panControl)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code works fine in the google code editor @ http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#control_position_v3

in the end the solution was to use `TOP_RIGHT` instead of `RIGHT_TOP`

Additionally the `index` property can be changed via `setAttribute` just like a majority of the other properties.

```
function initialize() {
   var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
   var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: { 
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
      }, 
      zoomControl: true, 
      zoomControlOptions: { 
         style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT, 
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP 
      }, 
      streetViewControl: true, 
      streetViewControlOptions: { 
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP 
      }, 
      panControl: false, 
      panControlOptions: { 
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP 
      }, 
      scaleControl: false, 
      scaleControlOptions: { 
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT 
      } 
   });
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much the default layout. I still can't get the mapTypeControl above the pan tool. If you would like to give an example of that, that would be perfect.

Comment: If you went to the playground and pasted by code and pressed run you should have seen the map type selection in the top right and it was above all the other controls... what do you want a screen shot?

Comment: Although the hack proposed by Jay is limited in possible applications (as you can only set the order by dividing all controls in two groups) it definitely does work and might get the job done :) .

Comment: Thanks Dave, and I didn't think it was a hack !P And why didn't I get my 50 Bounty?!?! It's a conspiracy I tell you!

Comment: Oh, I see what you did. That hack doesn't work for me because I have custom controls and they push the map type control to the left. I think the best answer to this question is that google controls cannot be custom ordered.

Answer (score 2):

I don't realy have a solution unfortunately but acording to this page
[Google Map API V3 Controls](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html) user defined controls can be placed before the default ones by changing their index in DOM. Might this be the same problem, that the zoom-control has a lower index than the map/satelite control?
Not sure how you would go about changing the index but it might be an avenue to find a solution.

Oh and if you do find out how to solve it please paste your solution here. Might come in handy.